# Why am i getting nonstop message boxes?

Tags: c#, dialog

So i working on a breakout game and so far everything has been going well, but when i make the the ball picturebox go off screen i seem to getting an unlimited amount of message boxes.

`here is the code snippet`

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Brick> bricks = new List<Brick>();
    Ball _ball;
    Paddle _paddle;
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime startTime2 = DateTime.Now;

    float ballVelocityX = 0;
    float ballVelocityY = -1;
    float ballSpeed = 20;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer2.Enabled = true;
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        System.Media.SoundPlayer sndPlayer;
        sndPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources._01_Calm_1);
        foreach (PictureBox brick in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (brick.Name != "ball" && brick.Name != "paddle")
                bricks.Add(new Brick(brick));
            else if (brick.Name == "ball")
                _ball = new Ball(brick);
            else if (brick.Name == "paddle")
                _paddle = new Paddle(brick);
            //sndPlayer.Play();

        }
    }

    private void gameTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBrickCollision();
        checkPaddleCollision();
        checkBallScreenBounds();

        ball.SetBounds(ball.Location.X + (int)(ballVelocityX * ballSpeed),
            ball.Location.Y + (int)(ballVelocityY * ballSpeed),
            ball.Size.Width, ball.Size.Height);
        paddle.SetBounds(Cursor.Position.X - panel1.Location.X, paddle.Location.Y,
            paddle.Size.Width, paddle.Size.Height);
    }

    private void checkBallScreenBounds()
    {
        if (_ball.BallRectangle.Location.X + 25 > panel1.Size.Width)
            ballVelocityX *= -1;
        else if (_ball.BallRectangle.Location.X < 0)
            ballVelocityX *= -1;
        else if (_ball.BallRectangle.Location.Y < 0)
            ballVelocityY *= -1;
        else if (_ball.BallRectangle.Location.Y > panel1.Size.Height)
            ballOffScreen();
    }

    private void ballOffScreen()
    {
        new_start();
        Startnew startnew = new Startnew();
        startnew.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void new_start()
    {            
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - startTime2;
        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show("Your total time is " + ":" + elapsedTime.Minutes + elapsedTime.Seconds
            + " would you like to play aigan?", "Application1", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.Show();
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        //MessageBox.Show("Total time is " + elapsedTime.Minutes + ":" + elapsedTime.Seconds);

    }

    private void checkPaddleCollision()
    {
        int tmpBallVelocityX = _paddle.CheckPaddleMovement();

        if (_ball.BallRectangle.IntersectsWith(_paddle.PaddleRectangle))
        {
            ballVelocityX = tmpBallVelocityX;
            ballVelocityY *= -1;
        }
    }

    private void checkBrickCollision()
    {
        Rectangle ballRectangle = _ball.BallRectangle;

        foreach (Brick brick in bricks)
            if (brick.IntersectWith(ballRectangle))
            {
                bricks.Remove(brick);
                ballVelocityX *= -1;
                ballVelocityY *= -1;
                break;
            }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Hide();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Show();
    }
    public void Form_closse(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //ProgramInfo.ProgramState = State.Splash_Screen;
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelTime.Text = "It is " + DateTime.Now;
    }
    private void timer2_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
        labelElapsedTime.Text = "Time Elapsed " + elapsedTime.Minutes + ":" + elapsedTime.Seconds;
      }
    }
  }
    ` #**EDIT**#`
    `**because things were getting a bit confusing i posted all my code.**`
```

ive done this with a button and it works fine and all, but i need to pop up only once. is there any way to only have it called once?

Comment: My guess is that your ball continues to move after it has gone offscreen and that every time it moves it causes ballOffScreen() to be called. Do you have any code to stop moving the ball after it's gone offscreen?

Comment: yes sir that is exactly whats happening, the sad part is i dont seem to know how to write that code from keeping it from thinking that its on an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if new_start() is part of Form1,

Following line looks like culprit, but more code is required for closer look.

```
if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show(); //This line is creating endless messagebox on selecting NO
    }
```

**UPDATE** Based on information in comments,

you can control the new_start function with flag

```
private bool checkNewGame = false;
private void new_start()
{        
    if(checkNewGame) return; 
    checkNewGame = true;    
    TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - startTime2;
    DialogResult result;
    result = MessageBox.Show("Your total time is " + ":" + elapsedTime.Minutes +   elapsedTime.Seconds
        + " would you like to play aigan?", "Application1", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
       checkNewGame = true; 
       this.Close();

    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

Instead of

```
if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Show(); //This line is creating endless messagebox on selecting NO
}
```

do something like

```
if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    this.Clear(); // Create new function Clear, and clear all the Form state.
}

void clear()
{
  ... //RESET all form state
}
```

Comment: i can give you more code but even with out the form1.show it would do the same thing, im just using that so that when the ball goes off the screen and they hit yes to the dialogresult it would reset itself. @Tilak

Comment: are you using any timer. also, how many times new_start(), or ballOffScreen is called? and what is your expected behavior

Comment: Yes i am using 3 timers one for the game and 2 for the time. i only made it to be called once but it does not seem to be going as planned. my expect behavior is that once the ball goess out of the control box that that messagedialog result box is to be called on and depending on the answer either it closes or calls back to reset the game and begins a new round.

Comment: seems like once ball goes out of control box, restart does not resets the ballOffScreen mode (it is called multiple times). It can be controlled using flag. Updated the code for the same.

Comment: well i seem to have up dated and part of it works, its just nw instead of getting infinite loops i get it to call on that but it will close down and repeat for another few times. i posted my entire code that i am using on the form i hope that will be a little less vague that what it was when i started.

Comment: Instead of creating new form everytime on DialogResult.No, cant you use a Clear method. In the clear method, resets all the class member. Create Form1 every time is not good idea (from GC point of view)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the code that supposed to restart the game does not clear "ball-Off-Screen" condition and your game immediately goes to end of game.

Note: Debugging should immediately show the reason of the behavior...

Comment: No i ran this is de-bugging mode it shows nothing. I think i might know why its doing it, im sure maybe it has to do with the boundaries. the ball probably keeps thinking that its is going out of the boundaries and infinite amount of times, do you anyway i could probably create some kinda of way to stop it?

Comment: There is no code that adjust position of the ball for new game. Please make sure when new game starts the ball is inside bounds.